# Move Xcode Simulator files to an external drive?

Tags: hard-drive, mac, external-hard-drive, xcode, simulator

I have Xcode installed and since my Mac has a small main storage I was forced to use an external drive where I moved Xcode.

The thing is that currently I don't have an iPhone that supports iOS 13 and I need to use the Simulator app.
I only used 1 device (the 11 Pro Max) and it has taken up 1.4GB in the main storage of my Mac.

Is it possible to move Simulators files the same way I did with Xcode, and use the external drive for r/w no the Macs storage?

Check the screenshots for more details as where they currently reside and how much storage they take:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vU0S8.jpg

P.S. I also have cleared the files but once I use it again, the files will be rewritten and waiting for the Simulator to get ready from scratch is really painful